# I want to clone with an existing Key in gitlite

Tags: git, ssh, key

my problem is the follow:

I wan't to clone from a gitlite Repository.
First I have a key on a old Linux System. But now I get windows. I copied the key to Windows. Then I want to clone the repository. But it don't work. When I wan't connect gitlite@remine.... .de, it will asked for a password. But I have only the key file. I have the file "helge" without ending. That's my Key. I have no Idea, and I don't found a solution. Can you help me?

Best regards,

Helge

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to configure ssh to use that key for that specific host.

You should put something like this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host remine.... .de
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/helge
```

Comment: In the .ssh folder is no config file in this folder.